# MATLAB prediction of data

Tags: matlab

I have a question in relation to the prediction of data in MATLAB.
I have x axis and y axis, i have to find the remaining data in y based on the available data.

Example:

x - 
10.08,
70.09,
130.1,
190.11,
250.12,
310.14,
370.15,
430.16,
490.17,
550.18

y - 
0,
0.03,
0.07,
0.1,
0.13,
0.17,
?,
?,
?,
?

Could any body please help me with the code, i tried poly-fit but only able to predict  value at a time.

Comment: What do you mean by "predict"?

Comment: hi thanks for reply, well I want to predict the rest of the y axis data according to x axis - which is time in an interval of 60 sec.

Comment: Nice edit. But there is no generalized way of "predicting" a time series. Do you have a method in mind? What is the context? You mentioned fitting the data with a polynomial? Yes you can do that but you need a basis for doing so.

Comment: well the context is to predicting the charging pattern of the battery. Y - axis is the charge capacity.

Comment: In that case, you would have to ask the question under battery. The only thing you can do without underlying theory is to record the "capacity" (however you are able to tell) from empty to fully charged over equal time steps and interpolate. (not extrapolate) Battery charging is quite complex. Make sure you control all environmental factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have some kind of model for your system. For example if you assume linear model then a simple linear fit will do it:

```
x=[10.08, 70.09, 130.1, 190.11, 250.12, 310.14];
y=[0, 0.03, 0.07, 0.1, 0.13, 0.17];

a=polyfit(x, y, 1); %linear fit
x_calc=[10.08, 70.09, 130.1, 190.11, 250.12, 310.14, 370.15, 430.16, 490.17, 550.18];
y_calc = polyval(a, x_calc);%prediction

figure(1);clf; 
plot(x,y,'o',x_calc,y_calc,'.');
legend('data','prediction','Location','northwest')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, able to get proceed further with this information.

Comment: Hi, Could you please let me know if i can use the similar code for non linear data or if you could suggest an alternative. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For parabolic model you can do polyfit(x, y, 2), for non linear you can have easy time if you use curve fitting tool "cftool". but you need install curve fitting toolbox